# Next.js i18n dynamic routes with getStaticPaths

Tags: routes, internationalization, next.js

I have a `/pages/[news]/index.js` defined with this `getStaticPaths` function:

```
export const getStaticPaths = ({ locales }) => {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { news: 'news' }, locale: 'en' },
      { params: { news: 'novitta' }, locale: 'it' },
      { params: { news: 'noticas' }, locale: 'es' },
    ],
    fallback: false,
  }
}
```

This gives me desired routing all going to `/pages/[news]/index.js` file:

- /news -> English news page
- /it/novitta -> Italian news page
- /es/noticas -> Spanish

Now I would like to add about page `/pages/[about.js]`

```
export const getStaticPaths = ({ locales }) => {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { about: 'about-us' }, locale: 'en' },
      { params: { about: 'chi-siamo' }, locale: 'it' },
      { params: { about: 'sobre-nosotros' }, locale: 'es' },
    ],
    fallback: false,
  }
}
```

to get these URLs:

- /about-us -> English news page
- /it/chi-siamo -> Italian news page
- /es/sobre-nosotros -> Spanish

But I get this error message: *Failed to reload dynamic routes: Error: You cannot use different slug names for the same dynamic path ('page' !== 'blog')*.

I do understand what the problem is but how can I solve this sort of routing?

Comment: Do you want your about page to be dynamic? Seems like you want something like `/pages/[locale]/about.js` and not `/pages/[about.js]`